# How to call TreeView set_model() from diffrent module?

Tags: python, user-interface, treeview, pygtk, multi-window

Im making GUI with PyGTK. Im stuck with updating content in gtk.TreeView(), its reading from json. I want to add a new position in json and update the set_model(new content). I will update the file from three places (add content, delete content, rename content). So problem occurs when the changing is made in different modules. Don't know how to access the set_model from another module, so when I change the content the gtk.ScrolledWindow (it is placed in gtk.Window) it displays the updated content. I think the problem is associated with autorefreshing(timer?) or iterating (forgot the names of functions) but not for sure. When the whole program was in one class it was easy to implement changes but hard to read, now (many modules) it is easy to read but hard to maintain. I will appreciate any answer.

Update:

```
class Catalogs(object):
    def _init_(self):
        self.the_tree = gtk.TreeView()
        <read from json>
        self.new_list.append(output from json)
        self.the_tree.set_model(self.new_list)
        print'new_list content will be printed but not displayed in window'
        self.window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.window.add(self.the_tree)
```

Comment: What I understand is that you update your treeview by changing (setting) a new model each time. From my understanding you only need to update the model itself (that is already set to the treeview) for the treeview to update itself. This way you can pass the model to each module and let them update the model to refresh the treeview. What I don't know is if there is going to be a concurrency issue or not. I guess if all changes take place in the same thread (loop) there shouldn't be.

Comment: There is no concurrency issue just writing to json and updating new content. Yes, I need to update the existing model and I don't know how to access the set_model method. I tried to make the argument for set_model method a global, or access it by getValue but none of them worked. I just write something for better understanding. Module have Class have _init_ have set_model.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with different 'modules'. Maybe you mean something else that what I'm thinking. If you want to run a function in another module that will update your treeview (and you don't want to update the model itself like I told you) then you have to pass the treeview object to that function for it to update it. I would be helpful if you could post some code and explain what you mean by 'many modules'.

Comment: Different module = a different class in another file. So how can I update window new content (list of keys from json) in the window  while the program is running ?

Comment: Like I told you before, when you update the model (ListStore for example) it will update the TreeView (you have to have set the model to it first). So you just have to pass the model to the function/method from the other module and update it. If you need to set a entirely new model to the TreeView then you have to use the ´set_model´ method. Since that method is a TreeView instance method, you must pass the TreeView object (in your case ´self.the_tree´) to wherever (the other module's function/method) it will be updated.

Comment: And that is the point of my question. I have troble with passing the model to three modules that each could update the content in treeview. Those are three connections to one treeview.

Comment: But you haven't even posted an error message. Nor shown what you're doing that doesn't work. You only posted a simple example of you code but using only one class/module, and you say your problem is using several. So I don't know how else to help you. With what I told you you should be able to do it.